# "you might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb" grammatical analysis

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, proverbs

How is the last part of "you might as well be hanged for a sheep as for a lamb" grammatically correct, that is "as for a lamb"?

Don't we use the structure "as for a something" in a sentence like "and as for you" (when it comes to you)?
Are there other examples of this usage - as for a lamb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two variants of the adage show different levels of deletion (as does the expanded but rarely met version), all acceptable:

- You might as well be hanged for {stealing} a sheep as [be hanged] for {stealing} a lamb.
- You might as well be hanged for                   
  a sheep as                        for
                     a
  lamb.
- You might as well be hanged for                   
  a sheep as
                                                   a
  lamb.

The omission of *stealing* assumes that the offence is obvious (historical knowledge presumed), while the other deletions are of a more familiar type, omitting repeats of words already given (or retrievable) while not leading to loss of clarity.

Comment: May I also add that the poetic quality of the phrasing gives it a pass were it not perfect. Though it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with the expression with *as a lamb*, rather than *as for a lamb*.

But the *as for* form is perfectly grammatical. You're right that the phrase *as for* has a particular meaning of its own, but here we have the accidental sequence of *as* and *for*, so it does not have that meaning.

A [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sheep%20as%20a%20lamb%2C%20sheep%20as%20for%20a%20lamb&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) of "sheep as a lamb" vs "sheep as for a lamb"  shows the former is always more common than the latter, though between 1980 and 2000 for some reason it was only about twice as common: at most times since 1820 the ratio has been higher.

Comment: thanks, would it be correct if we said "you might as well be hanged for a sheep as be hanged for a lamb"

Comment: Yes. The parallelism can work at several different levels.